# Subgradient of extension of convex function.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $X $ be a  convex and compact subset of $R^n$. There is a function $f :X \to R$ which is smooth & convex. It is known that $f$ can be extended to a convex $f_{ext}:R^n \to R$ as follows:

$f_{ext}(x)=f(x) $ if $x \in X$

$f_{ext}(x)=\infty $ if $x \notin X$

What is the subgradient of $f_{ext}$? Can it be proved that subdifferential of$ f_{ext}$, $\partial   f_{ext}(x)= \nabla f(x)+\partial I(x)$ (where $I(x)$ is the indicator function of set $X$ defined as:  $I(x)=0 $ if $x \in X$ else $I(x)= \infty$.)?

Comment: My understanding of convex functions is that they must be defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (or whatever other real vector space), but are permitted to take the value $\infty$ (or $-\infty$, sometimes). So, I would say $f$ is not technically a convex function, and would represent it by $f_{\mathrm{ext}}$ instead. I don't know, for example, how to define $\partial f(x)$ where $x$ is in the boundary of $X$. How do you define the subderivative at a point in the boundary of the domain?

Comment: @TheoBendit this is not quite correct. It is not necessary for any function, convex or otherwise, to be defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$. A function's domain may indeed be a strict subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (or any vector space). For a convex function, this domain must be a convex set. That said, we often adopt a so-called _extended-real_ convention where we define the value of a convex function to be $+\infty$ outside of its domain; this enables us to talk about it as defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$. But this really is just a convention.

Comment: @MichaelGrant For a **convex** function (not a function in general), the way that I learned the theory, the function must take (possibly infinite) values at every point in a vector space. The "domain" refers to points that don't map to $\infty$, which is different to the domain in the classic sense. We're not saying anything different, really, but my point is, I only know the definitions of subgradients for my convention for defining convex functions. As far as I'm concerned, the way to represent $f$ as a convex function is with $f_{\mathrm{ext}}$, so I'm not certain what's being asked here.

Comment: It may sound like nitpicking but I think it’s worth it. What you are describing is what is called the _extended real convention_ for defining convex functions. It is _just_ a convention—a way of simplifying the way convex functions are considered and manipulated. It is _not_ necessary, and it is artificial. “Infinity” is not a real number, after all: for any two real numbers $x$ and $y$, for instance, the value of $x-y$ exists—but this is not the case if $x=y=+\infty$. So in _absence_ of this convention, a function can have a domain that is a strict subset of the surrounding vector space.

Comment: For more information, look at Section 3.1.2 of Convex Optimization by Boyd & Vandenberghe, where it is clearly indicated that the use of infinities is a convenience.

Comment: What do you mean by $f :X \to R$ be smooth  a function? !

Do you mean $f$ is smooth on $int X $ ?

Comment: @Redshoes yes, f is smooth on $int(X)$

Comment: @Theo It is clear that in interior of X ,sub grad of $f_{ext}$ is $\nabla f$, but the real question is what is subgrad on   boundary of X? Is there a way to prove the above proposition?

Comment: @MichaelGrant $\infty - \infty = \infty$ in the convention as I've learned it. It makes sense; you can subtract convex functions of different domains, but it's only sensible on the intersection of the domains. I'm aware that it's a convenience, but the issue is that I don't know what's being asked here. It's fine to have different conventions, but I have no idea how you would define the subgradient of a convex function at a boundary point of the domain, unless it is to basically define it to be equal to $\partial f_{\operatorname{ext}}$. I just don't understand the problem.

Comment: $\infty-\infty$ is undefined and care must be taken to avoid it. Honestly the questioner is effectively asking if the subgradient is the same with the convention, and of course it is. The subgradient at the boundary points is definitely interesting and worth determining. Outside of the domain of course it is empty.

Comment: @Manu I have no idea what the subgradient is on the boundary of $X$, unless it's defined to be $\partial f_{\mathrm{ext}}$. If someone has asked me what the subgradient of $f$ was, I would guess that the definition of subgradient for convex functions defined on convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ would coincide with the definition of the subgradient of $f_{\mathrm{ext}}$. But since you're asking me to prove that they're the same, I'm lost. As I understand it, there's no question. But maybe Michael Grant can help you?

Comment: Actually, for a convex function to be smooth on its entire domain, its domain must be open, and if the domain isn’t the entire vector space, it must approach $+\infty$ on any boundary point. So this question really is a simple one, because no boundary conditions need be considered. If the function was not smooth there would be work to do!

Answer (score 0):

Note that for the function $f:X \to \Bbb R$  $$\partial f(\bar{x}) = \{ y \in \Bbb R^n ~|~~ \langle y , x -\bar{x} \rangle  \leq f(x) - f(\bar{x})  ~~  \forall x \in X \} $$
$$=  \{ y \in \Bbb R^n ~|~~\langle y , x -\bar{x} \rangle  \leq f(x) - f(\bar{x})  ~~  \forall x \in \text{dom } f = \text{dom } f_{ext} \} $$
$$= \partial   f_{ext}( \bar{x})$$

What convex analysis tells you for subdifferential at boundary of $X$ is that $$     \partial f(x) := \partial   f_{ext}(x) $$

Thus writing subdifferential of $f_{ext}$ in terms of subdifferential of $f$ is trivial since they coincide.

Note that $$\partial   f_{ext}(x)= \nabla f(x)+\partial I(x)$$
is not true when $x \in$ boundary of $X$. Since $f$ is smooth on only $\text{int}X $

By the way $\partial I (\bar{x}) = N (\bar{x} ; X).$

As an example think about the function $f[-1,+1]  \to R$ with $f(x) = - \sqrt{1-x^2}. $ what would be the $\partial f (1)$

**HOWEVER** if $\nabla f : \text{int} X \to R^n$ be bounded function then we have  $$  \partial   f_{ext}(\bar{x})=  \text{Lim Sup}_ {x \to \bar{x}}  \nabla f(x)+\partial I(\bar{x}) $$

Comment: Why limsup? Can we write some formal proof for the above statement? Intuitively it looks correct!

Comment: I don't mean the traditional limsup in $R$.

I mean the outer limit . @Manu